# Count of documents by column

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am trying to find the count of entries in a Domino database using a lotus-script based on a certain column.  I have created the following script below which runs okay but the message box total is a few hundred less than the total in the dialogue presented at the close of the script.  I am assuming one is including all the parent categories etc.  How do I count the number of records in the view based on the "Date Created" column?

I have included an image of the column I want a total for in the view.

[image]

```
Sub Initialize
   Dim db As NotesDatabase
   Dim view As NotesView
   Dim s As NotesSession
   Dim NotesDocColl As NotesDocumentCollection
   Dim requestDoc As NotesDocument
   Dim lngDocCount As Long

   Set s = New NotesSession
   Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
   Set view = db.GetView("By Category")
   Set requestDoc = view.Getfirstdocument()
   lngDocCount = 0
   Do Until requestDoc Is Nothing
       lngDocCount = lngDocCount + 1
       Set requestDoc = view.GetNextDocument(requestDoc)
   Loop
   MessageBox "Number of documents = " & lngDocCount
End Sub
```

Comment: Does each document appear in one and only one category?? My guess is that's not the case.

Comment: What are you trying to find out? How many documents are selected in the view or how many documents in the view have a specific date created or what? Are you unable to create an alternate view based on date created that you can traverse?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz I apologise for late feedback but it was a public holiday yesterday here in Scotland.  No each created document is unique.  Thanks

Comment: @Newbs I apologise for late response but it was a public holiday yesterday here.   There are 98 categories, Strategic Investment Group is just one of them.  What I want to find out is the total documents created for ALL the 98 categories in the view and also preferably the total documents in each category too.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a NotesViewNavigator object. This powerful tool allows you to leverage the work your view is doing for you generating totals, counts, calculated column values, etc, without the overhead of having to instantiate each document object. For your example try this snippet:

```
Sub Initialize
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim view As NotesView
    Dim nv As NotesViewNavigator
    Dim e As NotesViewEntry
    Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection   
    Set db = session.Currentdatabase
    Set view = db.getview("Categories")
    Set nv = view.Createviewnav()
    Set e = nv.Getfirst()

    Dim categcount, totalcount
    While Not e Is Nothing
        If e.Indentlevel=3 Then
             categcount = e.Childcount '<-do something with this value
             totalcount = totalcount+categcount
        End If  
        Set e = nv.Getnext(e)
    Wend
End Sub
```

Check out all the properties of a NoteviewEntry class. You may find some other useful things like .Siblings

Answer (score 0):

The following code will get you the "total documents created for ALL the 98 categories in the view":

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Dim s As NotesSession
Dim NotesDocColl As NotesDocumentCollection

Set s = New NotesSession
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase

Set view = db.GetView("By Category")
Set NotesDocColl = db.Search(view.Selectionformula, Nothing, 0)
MessageBox "Number of documents = " & NotesDocColl.Count
```

To get the number of docs for each category, I add a column to the view that computes to 1, and is totaled (bottom of the sort tab in designer) with "Hide detail rows" selected. Most times it is the first column in the view.

To get it programatically I use a NotesViewNavigator and iterate through the top level categories.

Comment: I added a comment for you above